# Getting an error sanitizing data form validation

Tags: php, pdo, sanitize

I am getting some errors around sanitising form data and kicking up this error, I am new to this so be patient with me- moving mysqli to PDO is a new world which I am learning:

Validate.php

```
    <?php
        class Validate {
            private $_passed = false,
                    $_errors = array(),
                    $_db = null;

            public function __construct() {
                $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
            }

            public function check($source, $items = array()) {
                    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
                        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){

                            $value = trim($source[$item]);
                            $item = escape($items);

                            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                                $this->addError("{$item} is required");

                            }    else if(!empty($value)){
                                    switch($rule) {
                                        case 'min':
                                            if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                                                $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters");
                                            }
                                        break;
                                        case 'max':
                                            if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                                                $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters");
                                            }                               
                                        break;
                                        case 'matches':
                                            if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                                                $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                                            }
                                        break;
                                        case 'unique':
                                            $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array('$item', '=', '$value'));
                                            if($check->count()){
                                                $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                                            }
                                        break;
                                    }

                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if(empty($this->_errors)) {
                        $this->_passed = true;
                    }

                    return $this;

            }

            private function addError($error) {
                $this->_errors[] = $error;  
            }

            public function errors() {
                return $this->_errors;
            }

            public function passed() {
                return $this->_passed;  
            }

So here is my sanitize file:

<?php
function escape($string) {
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QOUTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

I get this error when I include

```
$item = escape($items);
```

Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...

The same Error I get when I add a value to a  form field such as this:

```
<?php echo Input::get('name'); ?>
```

If somebody could advise a better method or advise where I have gone wrong I would be most appreciative...

Comment: Use parameterised queries, then you don't have to worry about 'sanitizing'.

Comment: But I would like to see what the error is in this case?

Comment: `ENT_QOUTES` - you also have a typo, you probably mean `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: Damn, I changed it but still the same error...

Comment: You're passing an array to your function here: `$item = escape($items);`.

Comment: So what will I need to amend?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is used with strings

try this

replace `$item = escape($items);` by `$item = escape($value);`

regards